# Eclipse Jar folder access

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

For a personal project I needed a French Text To Speech engine that I'll use from another application. So I created a simple Java code which says in French the argument 0 of the command (for example the command:)

> java -jar Speech.jar "Hello guys this is a test"

will say the sentence "Hello guys this is a test". To accomplish this I use a module named SI_VOX which uses a folder to get all the language data. In the Eclipse IDE engine, everything works but as soon as i compile my code to a runnable jar file, it says that the code isn't able to access the language data file.
The error is in French:

> SI_VOX WARNING [GenerateurPreposition] : Erreur lors du chargement du fichier de regles
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullnull (The system cannot find the file specified)

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import t2s.son.LecteurTexte;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0) return;
        final LecteurTexte lecteur = new LecteurTexte();
        for(String arg : args) { System.out.println(arg); }
        lecteur.setTexte(args[0]);
        lecteur.playAll();
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the data folder in my project (The code isn't able to access it when it is compiled but it is able to access it from the IDE).
(It is the "donees" folder)
[image]

Comment: Is the file included in the jar? If not, you'll have to customize your packaging process.

Comment: Hum... I don't know, It is maybe the clue, how do we change these packaging processes ?

Comment: How do you build your executable? Speech.jar I mean.

Comment: I only build it as an executable jar with Eclipse with no special things

Comment: If you decompile/unzip the jar, do you see si_vox.conf in the right path?